# Mac Mini running El Capitan Server unresponsive

Tags: macos, osx-server

I have a Mac mini (Late 2012),  2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 Processor, 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Memory that runs OS X Server 5.1.7.

Three times recently (I think since the upgrade to Server 5.1.7), the machine has become completely unresponsive and I have had to reboot it. On both occasions the fan was blowing full blast.

Given the complete lack of response I get the impression the CPU is completely tied up, but I can't see what process/es is/are causing it.

After the second occurrence I poked around in the log files a bit. In `system.log` I found the following, which had been repeating for hours:

```
 Aug  4 10:06:11 s-mx-01 configd[88]: could not allocate mach port: (os/kern) no space available
```

I went back and tried to find out when it had started and found this:

```
 Aug  3 18:05:44 s-mx-01 configd[88]: BUG in libdispatch: 15G31 - 384 - 0x1000600c
 Aug  3 18:05:44 s-mx-01 configd[88]: could not allocate mach port: (os/kern) no space available
```

Does anyone have any idea what this might mean? And how to fix it?

Comment: It has run out off a resource - by the wording I would suggest either RAM or disk

Comment: You may also want to contact Apple since `libdispatch` is part of Swift 3.  I would start with checking for updates and if all else fails, contact their support teams directly.

Comment: @Mark: I thought it might have run out of disk, but the disk is only 21% full. I'll check RAM.

Comment: @Allan: so I'm looking for a memory leak in a Swift 3 program...

Comment: Probably.  But I don't have experience with Swift, but this is what I would look for.

Comment: the console message might not be the app that is leaking the issue could be that another app is taking all the memory. Use Activity Monitor to confirm which app is taking memory

Comment: @Mark: unfortunately I've been unable to get into the system to monitor its state when the problem manifests itself, so I haven't been able to use Activity Monitor to analyse the problem.

Comment: Stephen, Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem, generally preceded with configd: BUG in libdispatch. Running 10.12 and server 5.2 MV

Comment: No, I never found the cause, though it seems to have gone away. Not sure how or when. I used `killd` on it a few times...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get into the system while it was manifesting the above symptoms. `configd` itself was consuming around 140% CPU; and there were 10 (!) instances of `smtpd`, each consuming around 40% CPU. Killing `configd` restored sanity (including removal of all the `smtpd` processes).

To find out what `configd` was up to I executed `sudo configd -v` and the system seized up and had to be rebooted. So it seems to be a `configd` problem.

The call of `configd -v`deposited the following in `system.log`:

```
Aug 22 09:29:53 s-mx-01 sudo[26480]: macowner : TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/Users/macowner ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/libexec/configd -v
Aug 22 09:29:53 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: pthread_set_qos_class_self_np() failed: Operation not permitted
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: SCDynamicStoreCreate() failed: Permission denied
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: kernel event monitor disabled
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: SCPreferencesScheduleWithRunLoop() failed: Permission denied
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: SCDynamicStoreCreate() failed: Permission denied
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: Network information server: Connection invalid
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: DNS configuration server: Connection invalid
Aug 22 09:29:54 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: Connection invalid
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: flush_routes: removing route for 169.254.101.43 failed: No such process
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: flush_routes: removing route for 169.254.173.101 failed: No such process
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: flush_routes: removing route for 169.254.221.184 failed: No such process
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: flush_routes: removing route for 169.254.224.132 failed: No such process
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: IPMonitor ip_plugin_init SCDynamicStoreCreate failed: Permission denied
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: SCDynamicStoreCreate() failed: Permission denied
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: SCNC Controller: notify_register_check failed, status = 1000000
Aug 22 09:29:55 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: EAPOLController: SCDynamicStoreCreate() failed, Permission denied
Aug 22 09:29:56 s-mx-01 configd[26484]: IPConfigurationSCPreferencesSetCallback failed: Permission denied`
```

My current theory is that there is a configuration problem in the mailing system which unhinges `configd`.